# What could be wrong in this code? i m getting "gs is not defined" error

Tags: python-3.x

I'ts working when I print inside def main(). so I "return gs" and printed outside. But still its giving me
*gs not defined error*

Here is the code:

```
def main():
    p.init()
    screen = p.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
    clock = p.time.Clock()
    screen.fill(p.Color("white"))
    gs = chessengine.GameState()
    return gs

main()
print(gs.board)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not assigning the value returned by `main` to a local variable, so when you reference `gs` in your `print` statement it is out of scope.  Instead, this should work:

```
gs = main()
print(gs.board)
```